# Handling class deletion in python if it is re-instantiated

Tags: python, class, garbage-collection, initialization

I am writing a class to communicate with an instrument (A Pico TC08 thermocouple reader), this instrument has a C library. I connect to the instrument when the class is initialized and deleted it in the `__init__` and `__exit__` methods.

```
  def __init__(self):
    self.device_handle = tc08.usb_tc08_open_unit()
    assert_pico2000_ok(self.device_handle)

  def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    status = tc08.usb_tc08_close_unit(self.device_handle)
    assert_pico2000_ok(status)
```

This works great when I instantiate the class with a "instr = PicoTC08()" and use it's methods using an instr.something.
However the issue is that if I try to initialize it again with something like this:

```
instr = PicoTC08()
instr = PicoTC08()
```

I get an error of "picosdk.errors.PicoSDKCtypesError: Unsuccessful API call".
How can I make sure that the first instance closes its connection to the instrument with an `__exit__` or other method before the second instance is initialized?

Comment: You probably want to use this as a context manager, i.e. in a `with` statement, but you need to define an `__enter__` as well.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using a with statement as I intend for this to be used with many (5ish) other devices at the same time and using a with that way seemed to be cumbersome. Is there a nice way I could use a with statement along with many devices?

Comment: are you just worried about the nesting? You can always do `with Picto() as instr1,  Picto() as instr2, Picto() as instr3(): ...`

Comment: That's part of it, the other instruments (not PicoTC08's) are able to get re-initialized without issue so it's handy to initialize them all at the start and just use them as needed without the need for a with statement.
There are also methods within this class that spawn a thread and continuously run / log data and those would be handy to be able to kick off without using using it in a "with" statement.